# Compare 2 data frames and find best match. Python (Pandas & NumPy)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, compare

Im trying to build process with choose best "plant" to source a material.
I have 2 data frames one with negative stock in warehouse , second one where we can source the stock.

1st dataframe "short":

```
     Plant  5501  5502  5503  5504  5506  5556
0  407500     0   -15     0     0     0     0
1  407400     0     0    -8     0     0     0
```

2nd dataframe:

```
    Plant  5501  5502  5503  5504  5506  5556
0  407500   100     0    40     0    10     1
1  407400   230    10     0     0     3     1
```

What Im looking for is a way to be able to find in 1st data frame short (407500 (-15 in 5502) & 407400 (-8 in 5503) and then be able to cover using the highest Plant from 2nd dataframe ( for 407500 to choose 5501 as stock is 100 there) & for 407400 to choose also 5501 as we have highest stock there as well.

Any ideas how I can approach this ? Thank you in advance

So fare I have managed to load inforamtions and create data frame

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook
alert = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\OneDrive - CCEP\Desktop\Python database\alert.xlsx' , sheet_name='Sheet1')
stock = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\OneDrive - CCEP\Desktop\Python database\stock.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(alert)
print(stock)
```

and try to compare this using array but I have stuck what is the best method to compare them.

```
alert.values
stock.values
```

I think if anyone can even help me how to approach this I will try to look for some code. Thank you guys

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit[ to include your code and your expected output to make a [mcve]

Comment: first try to do anything - not try to search "the best"

Comment: thx, I understand I dont have much code. Im trying now to find a ways to be able compare position x & y ( material & plant ) with same address in second array. But I cant find how to do it. If I know shall I use array or better compare 2 data frames in Pandas this is enough for me to start looking correct code